# Lync 2013 Does Not Maintain IM Window Size Or Position

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, lync, lync-2013

I am using **Windows 7 64-bit** and I just upgraded from **Lync 2010** to **Lync 2013**.

In **Lync 2010**, after you closed an IM, the next IM opened would be the previous IM's size and position.  From my experience so far, this is not the case with **Lync 2013**.

How do I make **Lync 2013** save the IM window size and position?

---

**Details that may or may not make a difference:**

1. I have a dual monitor setup and my Lync windows are typically on my 2nd monitor.
2. With respect to position and size, I usually drag the IM to the top right corner of my 2nd monitor and then resize the bottom of the window by dragging it down and snapping it to the bottom of the monitor.

Comment: So it doesn't remember where you left it when you closed it last?  Are you disconnecting/reconnecting the second monitor in between uses?

Comment: @techie007 - No and No. It just pops up a small window that I have to resize and reposition every time.

Comment: Have you seen: [Set conversation window size for Lync 2013](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0c77fb1b-2e3c-403a-a734-4fc5027f80a8/set-conversation-window-size-for-lync-2013?forum=lyncprofile) on MS' site yet?

Comment: @techie007 - I did not see that, I find it odd that I would have to manage a regkey every time I wanted to change the size and position of my window.  It doesn't remember the position and size from the last IM that was closed like virtually every other program?

Comment: Dunno, Lync 2010 (last version I used) remembered it, as far as I can remember (it's been over a year for me), and that's usually how MS deals with window placement.  Maybe it's a bug in 2013?

Comment: @techie007 - Yes ... I should have prefaced my question with that.  I just upgraded from 2010, which _did_ remember size and position (not 100% right, but 99%).  **Updated question**

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Upgraded from 2010 to 2013, now doesn't remember the previous window's size (it did in 2010).

Answer (score 3):

We just switched to Lync 2013 at my company and I ran into this issue.  I coded a very quick, very basic workaround in AutoHotKey.  It will resize (but not move) your chat windows.  Recall that this particular bug in Lync 2013 will remember your window position, but not window size.

The default window size is 430x430; this resizes the window to a much roomier 850x600.  Feel free to change the size in the script to suit your liking.  It only changes the size the first time the window appears.  If you proceed to resize the window, the script will not resize the window, nor will it remember the window size after you close it.  It will only set the window size the first time the window appears.

If you're unsure how to use AutoHotKey, check their awesome manual.

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, FixLyncWindow, 500

FixLyncWindow:
{
    IfWinExist, ahk_class LyncConversationWindowClass
    {
        ; First, get the HWND of the window. 
        ; Exit the loop if we have already resized it.

        WinGet, currID, ID
        IfNotExist, c:\temp\%currID%.txt
        {
            ; If we're here, we haven't acted on the window, 
            ; or no HWND file list exists,
            ; which also means we haven't acted on the window.
            ; So, it's finally time to act on the window.

            WinMove, ahk_id %currID%,,,, 850, 600

            ; Now, we add the HWND to the file so we know we've 
            ; already resized that window and we don't continue 
            ; resizing the window every half-second.

            IfNotExist, c:\temp
                FileCreateDir, c:\temp          
            FileAppend,, c:\temp\%currID%.txt
        }
    }

    ; Now, let's check the file directory to see if any of these 
    ; windows don't exist.  If they do not, we can delete the file.

    FileList = 
    test1 =
    Loop, c:\temp\*.*
    {
        SplitPath, A_LoopFileName,,,, myName
        FileList = %FileList%`,%myName%
    }

    Loop, parse, FileList, `,
    {
        If ( "%A_LoopField%" = "" )
            Return      

        IfWinNotExist, ahk_id %A_LoopField%
        {
            FileDelete, c:\temp\%A_LoopField%.txt
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: That solves part of the problem, but requires people to use **AutoHotKey**, it doesn't remember position, and I'm guessing that it probably doesn't re-size the reply area either which is one of my main annoyances.  That said, +1 for the effort.

Comment: @CodeMaverick The Lync bug (which has since been fixed with the transition to Skype for Business) only had issue with window size, not position.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has quite a few references found on Google, but for some reason has not made it into the list of [Lync 2013 known issues](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/lync-help/lync-2013-known-issues-HA102919641.aspx).

There is one workaround [posted](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6962c325-d85f-4162-84c1-1040ce95ebf1/lync-2013-desktop-client-on-windows-8-sizing-and-start-location-issues?forum=lyncprofile) that worked for some but not for others :

> 1. Open several conversations with the tabbed conversation setting turned on.
> 2. Move that window to the place you want it to be.
> 3. Close the window.
> 4. Subsequent windows will open in that position.

You could also have a look at the registry as detailed in
[Where are Lync Client Settings Stored?](http://lyncdup.com/2011/05/where-are-lync-client-settings-stored-hint-registry/) and especially the positional parameters :

`IMWindowHeight, IMWindowMax, IMWindowRect, IMWindowWidth`

Although not much is known about their effect (if any).

Comment: Yea, that was one of the first things I tried.  Didn't work for me.

Comment: Playing with the registry parameters is the only advice I have left, although you will be in an uncharted territory. With Microsoft choosing to ignore that problem, I just remark that Lync is not the only IM tool around.

Comment: It is if your employer requires you to do IM communications with your co-workers through it.

Comment: @harrymc - That reference link only pertains to older versions of Lync.  The newer 2013 version keeps the settings under `\HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync`.  It doesn't contain the `IMWindow*` options mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed annoying. My Issue started all of a sudden on Skype for Business 2015. Here is how I fixed it:
enable tabbed conversation, size/resize windows
close
restart SKB
disable tabs, exit
restart
will work

Comment: Could you possibly expand upon how to enable those features you mentioned? Ideally with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Under Settings / tools / Options, select IM to show the IM options. The "Enable tabbed conversations" is available in here...

[IM Settings / Tabbed Conversations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1abc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above nothing worked. Then I opened Skype for business by accident, which reverts back to Lync due to Group Policy settings, now all my Lync IM window sizes stick and work when they are resized.

Comment: How does it save `Lync IM window sizes and position` give more information please